# click event in parent of component not working in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, events, onclick, parent-child

I have nested component like this pattern

```
<div (click)="saveInfo()">
    <product-list-component>
      <single-product>
        <div (click)="navigateToDetailsProduct()"></div>
      <single-product>
    <product-list-component>
</div>
```

and I want when I click on single product both of click function (saveInfo() in parent and navigateToDetailsProduct() in child component) are executed.
but sometimes both of them are executed and some times just a click function in child component.
I glad to understand how can I trigger two function in parent and child component in angular.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger two functions in parent and child component angular at same time. when you will click on navigateToDetailsProduct() then this function along with saveInfo() will trigger. Please open below link and see.
Click on "Navigate To Details Product" you can see two alert will come 1st when navigateToDetailsProduct() will trigger and second when saveInfo() will trigger.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uvyacb?file=src/app/singleproduct.app.component.html

Let me know if you need anything more.

Comment: Thank you for your response
in my case I don't want to use output decorator; because there is not simple parent child relation. the relation is like what I write in question; if I use output and event Emitter I have to write output decorator for all the nested component.

Comment: I think I find out why it's happened.
the function in child component navigate to details product page and the saveInfo() function can't trigger.
I know in pure js can trigger click event in capturing phase but I don't know how can I write it in angular .

Comment: In angular you know if you want to communicate between components then you have to use input/output decorator . I don't think there are any other way to do this. Please go through this link you may get some solution. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: I don't want share data between components.
I want execute both function that one is in parent and one is in child 
I asked my new question in this post
if you have any idea I glad to hear and Thanks a lot.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69026412/how-fire-click-function-in-capturing-mode-in-angular